# Sum of a column by month using a Calculated Column

Tags: calculated-column

Here is the background to my question. We are uploading field data about various moth species caught by trap. These traps are checked every month, but not always on the same day of the month.The columns are date, trap number and total moths caught.
I would like to use a calculated column to show the total moths caught for each month.

Once I have the correct formula from my moth data list I can then quite easily chart it by total moths caught by month.

I know the formula would have to have YEAR and MONTH otherwise I would be adding January 2012 and January 2013 etc.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can can this (as a display only in a very dodgy way) via Group By on the view display options. Each group(column) shows how many items are in it at a current time (ie: Jan (58), Feb (12)). Easier if you export it to excel as per theChrisKent answer unless you want to create a second list and update it each time an item is added to listA

Answer (score 0):

A calculated column wouldn't make sense for what you're trying to accomplish. A calculated column is applied per item not per list, so it wouldn't be able to total multiple items.

The right solution depends on how you are wanting to chart these. If using Excel, then you can easily group the totals with a Pivot Chart using the list in its current form. Most of the other charting options can do something similar.